# AWS deployment types - Beanstalk or codedeploy

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have developed webapplication and generated war file. Before doing pipeline in aws , i want to choose the deployment options whether i can go with aws codedeploy or Elastic Bean Stalk. I want to know whether i can deploy the webapplication(.war) in aws code deploy? What is the benefits between code deploy and Elastic beanstalk. Which one is most preferable to choose for deployment and use in aws codepipeline.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely deploy whatever you want using AWS CodeDeploy. CodeDeploy is application agnostic and will deploy whatever bundle you give it and do what actions you specify on your instances.

AWS CodeDeploy and AWS Elastic Beanstalk are apples and oranges. CodeDeploy is a deployment service, so you need to create your own infrastructure (load balancers, capacity like EC2 or AutoScaling, etc), but you have full control over those resources. Elastic Beanstalk tries to simplify managing resources by doing it for you, including giving you a mechanism to do deployments to those hosts.